# Commented-out javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, comments

It could be that I'm going insane, but I have to know.

Wasn't it possible, at one time, to delimit Javascript blocks by putting them in `<!--` .. `-->`?

This was supposed to work, wasn't it?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
  alert('</script>');
 //-->
</script>
```

So to the HTML parser, everything is comment, and there's no end tag in there. Right? And the script will run in its entirety, right? Then why doesn't it? (Here, a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/TwU4w/)) Or am I losing my mind?

PS I know about solutions like putting a `\` in, using a .js file instead of inline Javascript, or various XHTML solutions such as encoding the `<` or using a CDATA block. But that's not what my question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those comments are only treated as a comment by browsers that *do not recognise the script element*. The purpose was to stop older browsers rendering JavaScript as text inside an unknown element.

Comment: So, not to keep the `</script>` inside from being found? Then maybe I _am_ losing my mind. Man.

Comment: Correct. The methods you describe in your PS are the appropriate way to handle the string `</script>` inside a script element.

Comment: OK. Well, what is there to say. OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use a double slash like this: `// Comment!`

Or for a block:

```
/*
This is a multi-line
comment block
*/
```

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // alert('</script>');
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
  alert('</script>');
*/
</script>
```

Comment: I was talking about HTML comments. With commented-out I didn't mean I didn't want the Javascript to run. I do want it to run!